# Optimizing sum of numbers in a list range

Tags: python, algorithm, list, for-loop

I am trying to answer a question on an online judge, but I keep running into time limit problems. The main idea of the problem is to solve the sum of a list minus the sum of a sublist within that list. The full problem specifications can be seen  [here.](https://dmoj.ca/problem/gfssoc2j4)

Here is my code:

```
import sys
lists = sys.stdin.read().strip().split('\n')

showScores = map(int, lists[1].split())
maximum = sum(showScores)
loops = map(int, lists[0].split())[1]

for i in range(2, loops+2):
    subList = lists[i].split()
    print maximum - sum(showScores[int(subList[0])-1 : int(subList[1])])
```

Is there a better algorithm for solving the problem? How should I approach this, considering I have to do up to 500,000 loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@IVlad gave a very helpful hint in his answer, and I'll take it one step further with examples.  Any time you can pre-compute values before a loop, the faster the loop will execute.  Running `sum()` on a slice will return the same value for the same slice every time, so pre-compute the sums before the loop.

If you generated a list of sums of the first `a` scores, it would look like this:

```
first = [0, 5, 11, 18, 26, 29, 33, 38, 44, 45, 47]
```

If you also generated a list of the sums of the last `b` scores, it would look like this:

```
last = [47, 42, 36, 29, 21, 18, 14, 9, 3, 2, 0]
```

Inside of your loop, you could then

```
print first[a-1] + last[b]
```

which is faster than taking a sum of a slice.

Comment: The general idea was to create another list of sums and use that to calculate the answer. The examples really helped.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid calling `sum` for each query. No matter how efficient the slicing, you still need to iterate that range to compute its sum, under your current setting. So you need to optimize your algorithm, not the code.

If you have:

```
S[i] = sum of the first i numbers
     = a[0] + a[1] + ... + a[i]
```

Which you can compute in `O(n)`:

```
S[i] = S[i - 1] + a[i]
```

How can you answer each query in `O(1)` by using `S`?

**Hint:** if you had to compute the sum of some interval `[x, y]`, we'd use:

```
S[y] = a[0] + a[1] + ... + a[x] + ... + a[y]
S[x] = a[0] + a[1] + ... + a[x - 1] + a[x]
```

Comment: As much as I agree with giving hints instead of complete solutions off hand, I don't think that this kind of answer fits SO's Q&A form. It rather fits a comment.

Comment: @MaciejGol it's too long for a comment. If you can find a better hint that doesn't give it all away, I'll delete it. The OP asked for an approach, and this is such an approach. It's one step from the full solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are hinting at. Do i have to add up to the beginning of the sublist and add after the end of the sublist?